# How to grant the client application access to the requested scope in microsoft azure

Tags: java, azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm getting this error

> com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalInteractionRequiredException:
> AADSTS70000: The request was denied because one or more scopes requested are unauthorized or expired. The user must first sign in and grant the client application access to the requested scope.
>
> Trace ID: add5eedb-86d5-41bc-bad3-129298e3ca00
> Correlation ID: 1d2ab508-8ec6-49d7-abaa-d1b8feaedda8

I register app in Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox) azure account

**API permission:**

Delegated:

- Calendars.Read
- Calendars.ReadWrite
- offline_access
- openid
- profile
- User.Read
- User.Read.All
- email
- Mail.Read

Application:

- Calendars.Read
- Calendars.ReadWrite

I give the required permission and scope (Expose an API) in azure portal still I'm getting this error. I tried to solve this error for more then a days I don't understand What am I doing wrong?

It was not asked calendar's permission when user login.

I have used msal4j version 1.6.1 dependency

[image]

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by adding `Calendars.ReadWrite` scope in AuthorizationRequestUrlParameters

---

In the below string `updatedScopes` I had passed null so it's consider default scope of Microsoft and not asked calendar permission.

```
String updatedScopes = scope == null ? "Calendars.ReadWrite" : scope;
        
PublicClientApplication pca = PublicClientApplication.builder(clientId).authority(authority).build();
AuthorizationRequestUrlParameters parameters = AuthorizationRequestUrlParameters
.builder(redirectURL,Collections.singleton(updatedScopes))
.responseMode(ResponseMode.QUERY)
.prompt(Prompt.SELECT_ACCOUNT).state(state).nonce(nonce)
.claimsChallenge(claims).build();
```