# Setup Microsoft Identify Platform and "Missing grant for this add-in" for localhost

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on, office-js, microsoft-identity-platform

I have an Excel add-in where single sign-on was implemented, but recently I realize that the SSO does not work anymore. So I tried to debug it in localhost.

First, I met the `Missing grant for this add-in` error in my add-in. Then, I had the same error with the sample project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart. Note that I don't have this error with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs.

I created a test Azure account: `test.sso.2023@gmail.com` and registered [the app](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/%7E/Overview/appId/e55f4769-4293-4b71-94ea-5eb16dcfe41d/objectId/f61962fb-722b-465f-a265-4a1e70a744e3/isMSAApp%7E/true/defaultBlade/Overview/appSignInAudience/AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount). I put the updated code of `sso-quickstart` that produces the error in [this repository](https://github.com/test-sso-2023/sso).

After launching the code we could sign in Excel Online in Chrome, then sideload the add-in. Clicking on the button `Get My User Profile Information` launched `Office.auth.getAccessToken`, which raised the error `POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token 400 (Bad Request)` and `Missing grant for this add-in.`

[image]

The request `https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token` returned

> AADSTS70000: The request was denied because one or more scopes requested are unauthorized or expired. The user must first sign in and grant the client application access to the requested scope...

[image]

The JSON of my settings on the Microsoft Identity Platform:

```
{
    "id": "f61962fb-722b-465f-a265-4a1e70a744e3",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "e55f4769-4293-4b71-94ea-5eb16dcfe41d",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2023-01-31T19:16:20Z",
    "description": null,
    "certification": null,
    "disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [
        "api://localhost:3000/e55f4769-4293-4b71-94ea-5eb16dcfe41d"
    ],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "sso",
    "notes": null,
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2Permissions": [
        {
            "adminConsentDescription": "Allow Office to have read/write permissions to all user files and read permissions to all user mail. Office can call the app's web APIs as the current user.",
            "adminConsentDisplayName": "Read/write permissions to user files. Read permissions to user mail and profiles.",
            "id": "9b6c01b1-9818-4eb3-898c-e412fad8ae03",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "type": "User",
            "userConsentDescription": "Allow Office to have read/write permissions to your files, and read permissions to your mail and profile.",
            "userConsentDisplayName": "Read/write permissions to your files. Read permissions to your mail and profile.",
            "value": "access_as_user"
        }
    ],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": null,
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": null,
            "endDate": "2023-07-30T18:17:18.762Z",
            "keyId": "10c2239b-b83c-4085-b277-a37931990aa1",
            "startDate": "2023-01-31T19:17:18.762Z",
            "value": null,
            "createdOn": "2023-01-31T19:17:25.3206496Z",
            "hint": "~l2",
            "displayName": "secret"
        }
    ],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [
        {
            "appId": "ea5a67f6-b6f3-4338-b240-c655ddc3cc8e",
            "permissionIds": [
                "9b6c01b1-9818-4eb3-898c-e412fad8ae03"
            ]
        },
        {
            "appId": "d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c",
            "permissionIds": [
                "9b6c01b1-9818-4eb3-898c-e412fad8ae03"
            ]
        },
        {
            "appId": "93d53678-613d-4013-afc1-62e9e444a0a5",
            "permissionIds": [
                "9b6c01b1-9818-4eb3-898c-e412fad8ae03"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "publisherDomain": null,
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "https://localhost:3000/fallbackauthdialog.html",
            "type": "Spa"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": null,
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

And API permissions which can also be found in the above JSON:

[image]

Does anyone know what may be the cause of this error?

(* [Link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3126) in Github office-js *)

Comment: One problem is that your Application (client) ID is "188 ... 57f", but in other places where  you should have the same GUID, you have "3cb ... ded".

Comment: Thank you. I did notice this, and planned to amend it.

Comment: I just amended the OP and re-did the test, the errors were still the same.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65845115/how-to-grant-the-client-application-access-to-the-requested-scope-in-microsoft-a

Comment: @TylerH I don't see how the answer of that question could help.

Comment: Hi @SoftTimur, are you getting permissions **consent screen** after selecting `get my user profile` option?

Comment: @Sridevi, could you be more precise? You mean the `Get My User Profile Information` button in the add-in or some option when I registered the app in Azure Portal?

Comment: I mean `Get My User Profile Information` button in the add-in

Comment: @Sridevi, After clicking on the `Get My User Profile Information` button in the add-in, I can see the errors in the devtools, and `sso wants to display a new window` in the add-in. After clicking `Allow` in the add-in, I can see the window with `Let this app access your info?`.

Comment: Check whether your **test Azure** user account has **[Global Administrator](https://i.imgur.com/2MCAROR.png)** role or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251550/discussion-between-sridevi-and-softtimur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I ran the below commands to create `My Office Add-in`  for **Excel** using JavaScript and Single-sign-on by selecting **required** options:

```
npm install -g yo generator-office
yo office
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now I ran `npm run configure-sso` that took me to browser where I picked one user credentials:

[image]

Once the login is successful, I got output saying new application is **registered** successfully in Azure AD and updated **source** files automatically like below:

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, Azure AD application is **registered** successfully with below details:

[image]

I have below **API permissions** added to the application automatically like below:

[image]

When I checked `Expose an API` tab, it added below details like App ID URI, scopes etc...

[image]

I have below **Redirect URIs** added to my application:

[image]

When I ran `npm start` command, it asked to install certificate initially like below:

[image]

This opened Excel with `My Office Add-in` where I got **consent screen** like below:

[image]

After consenting to the permissions, I got the **user profile** details successfully like below:

[image]

In your case, make sure to have one Azure account with **active** Azure subscriptions and assign **`Global administrator`** role to the **test user** account on that tenant, which is required to **consent** the permissions.

If you don't have **active** Azure accounts, get *Free Trial* subscription by clicking `Start free` button in this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/search/?OCID=AIDcmmf1elj9v5_SEM_e33a58e7ed46113f4eab3b3d79ffb86f:G:s&ef_id=e33a58e7ed46113f4eab3b3d79ffb86f:G:s&msclkid=e33a58e7ed46113f4eab3b3d79ffb86f).

Now, repeat the whole process by configuring the add-in again with this **user credentials**.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me debug this in chat, Sridevi.

Comment: I clicked too quickly and accidentally assigned the bounty to 
Eugene Astafiev. I will see if i can undo that. Really sorry about this.

Comment: I just realized that we can still start a bounty on this question. I will do that and award the bounty to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Redirect URIs: https://localhost:3000 (should it be https://localhost:3000 or https://localhost:8000?)

Of course. There is nothing running on localhost:3000. Everything should use the same URL.

Anyway, I'd suggest trying to create an empty add-in and use the automatic tool for registering the web add-in in Azure. Following that way you can be sure that SSO is working correctly for your tenant and the warning shown on the screenshot is not related to that  if the sample add-in is working correctly. Then you can start delving deeper with your existing solution to find the root cause.

The `configure-sso` NPM package can help setting things up correctly for your sample add-in. See [Single sign-on (SSO) quick start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart) for  a guide.

Comment: Thank you. I have the same error with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart, and amended the OP.

Comment: Well, then I'd suggest looking at the Azure side, not at the Office add-ins. Have you tried using Fiddler btw?

Comment: I have not used Fiddler, will it give more information than browser devtools?

Comment: I always forget about browser debugging tools in case of web add-ins. Still can't switch from COM add-ins :) Anyway, built-in tools don't provide all features of Fiddler, so I'd suggest using both.

Comment: I just tried Fiddler, I could see the error, but don't see more information than DevTools: https://i.postimg.cc/s21HP9gj/Screenshot-2023-01-31-at-23-50-42.png